# Extracting weights from model in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I use Tensorflow 2.0 and want to extract all weights and biases from a trained model. Here is what I did so far:

I create a model class:

class MyModel(Model):

```
def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__() # MyModel comes from a Basis Class
    self.conv1 = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=[2,2], activation='relu')
    self.flatten = Flatten()
    self.d1 = Dense(units=64, activation="relu")
    self.d2 = Dense(units=10, activation="softmax")

def call(self, x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)
    x = self.d1(x)
    x = self.d2(x)
    return x
```

During and after the training, I save my model:

```
checkpoint_path = "./logs/model.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = "./logs/"
self.model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)
self.model.save(checkpoint_dir)
```

At this point I ask myself already, how to save the model correctly? Do I use `save_weights` or just `save`? I want to be able to

1. retrain the model if necessary
2. extract the model's weights for further analysis

Currently I load my trained model (in a new file) by doing:

```
model = MyModel()
model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
```

But how can I access the network's weights? I already tried `tf.compat.v1.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)` which did not work.

I highly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the difference between two saving methods:

- model.save_weights(): You save only weights. So, you need the model code to reconstruct the model as `model = MyModel()` with initial weights. Then you replace weights by `.load_weights()`
- model.save(): It saves the whole model including the architecture, optimizer states and weights. So, you can reproduce the entire mode without the code that defines MyModel().
- By the way, another option in TF2 is to use [checkpoint manager](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/CheckpointManager).
  In your case, I would go with .save_weights() or checkpoint manager

Next, you can analyze the weights by:

```
import tf.keras.Model as Model
from tf.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__() # MyModel comes from a Basis Class
        self.conv1 = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=[2,2], activation='relu')
        self.flatten = Flatten()
        self.d1 = Dense(units=64, activation="relu")
        self.d2 = Dense(units=10, activation="softmax")

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.d1(x)
        x = self.d2(x)
        return x

m = MyModel()
input_shape = tf.TensorShape([None,64,64,1]) # For exmaple, 64x64 images with arbitrary batch size
m.build(input_shape) 

# Train

# Save weights 

# Load weights

# Analyze weights
conv1_weights, conv1_bias = m.conv1.weights
d1_weights, d1_bias = m.d1.weights
d2_weights, d2_bias = m.d2.weights
```